# pausing search history in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

chrome has no way to turn off search history. I have tried many online tutorials and none seem to work. how would I stop chrome from recording my browsing history without deleting all my history or using incognito mode?

Comment: I would in all honesty consider using a different browser; perhaps one whose entire raison d'être is not to sell user-targeted advertising. If you stick your head in the lion's mouth, don't complain when it bites you.

Comment: Something like [Brave](https://brave.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be to use the extension
[No History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-history/ljamgkbcojbnmcaonjokopmcblmmpfch?hl=en),
with which one can toggle off and on history.

You will find more information on using this extension in the article
[How to Permanently Stop Chrome from Recording Browsing History](https://www.zeumic.com.au/how-to-permanently-stop-chrome-from-recording-browsing-history/).

A more complicated way would be to set the Chrome history file to read-only
for the duration. This file (actually a database) is named `History` and is found at:

- Windows: `C:/users/user-name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default`
- MacOS : `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

Finally, to disable keeping history in your Google account, you may:

- Click your profile icon
- Click Manage your Google activity
- Click Data & personalization
- Under Activity controls, disable Web & App Activity
- Click Pause to confirm

To undo, follow the same path and enable Web & App Activity.

Comment: Do you know which, if any, of the solutions you provided would stop Chrome from using the history for [FLoC](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/privacy-2/2021/04/how-to-opt-out-of-the-google-floc-trial/) if that was enabled?

Comment: FLoC uses cookies, not the history, so none of these methods relate to it.

Comment: It's not my question. Also, according to [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/724441/what-is-googles-floc-and-how-will-it-track-you-online/), *FLoC lets advertisers use behavioral targeting without cookies. It runs in Google’s Chrome browser and tracks a user’s online behavior.

Then, it assigns that browser history an identifier*

Comment: For Windows the best solution would be to use Microsoft Edge which is basically Chrome without the marketing part. Or another Chromium clone.